# JOINING Two Tables together in SAS

Tags: sas

I am working on the this SAS code and would need assistance with joining the two tables below. I am getting errors while trying to join the two tables.

Requirement: i. Left Join Table B to Table A

Table A:

```
PROC SQL; 
 create table stand as select distinct
    put(datepart(Max(a.REPORT_DATE)),Date9.) as M_Date
  , a.BUSINESS_GROUP as PORTF_LEVEL1
  , A.SPLIT as PORTF_LEv2
  , Count(distinct a.Report_Date) as Number_of_Days 
  , (B.TOTAL_BREACH/Count(distinct a.Report_Date))*100 as FREQ 
  , A.MINIMUM_ACCEPTABLE_COUNT
  , A.MAX_COUNT 
  , (case WHEN (B.TOTAL_BREACH/Count(distinct a.Report_Date)) * 100 LT MIN_COUNT 
          THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as NUMBER__UNDER
  , (case WHEN (B.TOTAL_BREACH/Count(distinct a.Report_Date)) * 100 GT MAX_COUNT THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as NUMBER__OVER
 from temp a 
   INNER join 
   ( select BUSINESS_GROUP as PORTF_LEVEL1
           ,SPLIT AS PORTF_LEv2
           ,Count(distinct c.Report_Date) as Number_of_Days 
      from temp c 
        Inner join temp2 d 
      on c.Report_Date=d.Report_Date 
      WHERE &Alert and TENOR = '+'
        and datepart(c.REPORT_DATE) ge '31-APR-21'd
        and datepart(c.REPORT_DATE) le '31-APR-22'd
      Group by BUSINESS_GROUP, SPLIT
   )B 
  on a.BUSINESS_GROUP = b.PORTF_LEVEL1
  AND a.SPLIT = b.PORTF_LEVEL2 

 INNER JOIN temp2 e 
 on a.REPORT_DATE = e.REPORT_DATE 
 where &Alert and TENOR = '+'
   and datepart(a.REPORT_DATE) ge '31-APR-21'd
   and datepart(a.REPORT_DATE) le '31-APR-22'd 
 Group by Business_GROUP, SPLIT 
; 
QUIT;
```

Table B:

In the table B, i am trying to find the median of the variable Data_M. The code seems to be okay. I only need assistance joining the Table B to table A above.

```
Proc sql outobs=1; create table median_dt1 as select distinct put(datepart(max(REPORT_DATE)), date9.) as M_Date , median(Data_M) as median_data from transp
WHERE datepart(REPORT_DATE) ge '01-APR-22'd and datepart(REPORT_DATE) le '31-APR-22'd group by BUSINESS_GROUP order by Report_Date Desc; quit;
```

Thank you in advance!

sas

Comment: I don't really see what the question is here.  From the code you posted you appear to know how to join tables using SQL code.

Comment: |Hi Tom, I am getting errors while trying to join the Table B to Table A. Please can you help?

Comment: What code did you run to join them? What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
 from temp a 
   INNER join 
   ( select BUSINESS_GROUP as PORTF_LEVEL1
           ,SPLIT AS PORTF_LEv2
           ,Count(distinct c.Report_Date) as Number_of_Days 
      from temp c 
        Inner join temp2 d 
      on c.Report_Date=d.Report_Date 
      WHERE &Alert and TENOR = '+'
        and datepart(c.REPORT_DATE) ge '31-APR-21'd
        and datepart(c.REPORT_DATE) le '31-APR-22'd
      Group by BUSINESS_GROUP, SPLIT
   )B 
  on a.BUSINESS_GROUP = b.PORTF_LEVEL1
  AND a.SPLIT = b.PORTF_LEVEL2
```

You're trying to join on b.PORTF_LEVEL2. However, that column doesn't exist in B. The column "PORTF_LEV2" exists, though. Try that?

If that doesn't resolve the issue, please paste the complete error message that you're receiving.